# How to inject an event like button press programmatically in gtkmm C++?

Tags: c++, linux, linux-mint, gtkmm, gtkmm3

I am very new to C++ gtkmm (Linux) programming. I developing a program where I need a button to be clicked in the callback function of another button on the gui.
I have tried
button.activate()
But it only animates the button click but the callback function is not called. When I click the button manually, the callback function is called.
Please explain how to inject event into the gtkmm C++ coding. Events may include button press, key press etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example that works with Gtkmm 3.24 for a button click:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <gtkmm.h>

class MainWindow : public Gtk::ApplicationWindow
{

public:

    MainWindow();

private:

    Gtk::Grid m_layout;

    Gtk::Label m_label;

    Gtk::Button m_buttonA;
    Gtk::Button m_buttonB;

};

MainWindow::MainWindow()
: m_buttonA{"A"}
, m_buttonB{"B"}
{
    m_label.set_text("Click a button...");

    m_buttonA.signal_clicked().connect(
        [this](){
            std::cout << "Button A clicked!" << std::endl;

            // Emits "clicked" on button B, just like when
            // a user clicks it:
            m_buttonB.clicked();
            m_buttonB.activate_action("clicked");
        }
    );

    m_buttonB.signal_clicked().connect(
        [this](){
            std::cout << "Button B clicked!" << std::endl;
        }
    );

    m_layout.attach(m_buttonA, 0, 0, 1, 1);
    m_layout.attach(m_buttonB, 1, 0, 1, 1);

    add(m_layout);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::cout << "Gtkmm version : " << gtk_get_major_version() << "."
                                    << gtk_get_minor_version() << "."
                                    << gtk_get_micro_version() << std::endl;

    auto app = Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv, "org.gtkmm.examples.base");
  
    MainWindow window;
    window.show_all();
  
    return app->run(window);
}
```

With Gtkmm 4 however, the `clicked()` method seems to have been removed from `Gtk::Button`'s interface. By looking at the new interface, there is a `activate_action` method (inherited from `Gtk::Widget`) that, maybe, could work. However, I don't have Gtkmm 4 here, so I could not try it.

Comment: error: ‘class Gtk::Button’ has no member named ‘activate_action’
   39 |  button->activate_action("clicked");
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~           please explain what to do.

Comment: What is your Gtkmm version? Build and run this to find out:
`int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::cout << "Gtkmm version : " << gtk_get_major_version() << "." << gtk_get_minor_version() << "." << gtk_get_micro_version() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}`
I suspect you have Gtkmm 3 (and not 4).

Comment: Gtkmm version : 3.24.30

Comment: Ok, same as mine. In this version, `activate_action` is not yet available (you need Gtkmm 4). You can use the approach in the code snippet I posted in my answer instead.

Comment: But button.clicked() is not calling the callback. Please help.

Comment: Did you try the code I posted (exactly)? If not, you will have to post the code you are tying to run in your question. In the case of the code I posted, the callback is called (see output in console).

Comment: Yeah, I was using signal_button_press_event() not signal_pressed(). Now it's working. but how are these two functions different?

Comment: I don't know, I always use `signal_clicked`.